# Real time multi user interaction

Tags: c#, networking, p2p

The program I am making requires the use of real time cross computer interactions via the internet.

The issue I'm coming across is that while I wish for the clients to connect to a host client rather then going for a client server model there are a lot of problems in terms of getting the host client able to actually host (accept an incoming connection, etc.)

I'm trying to make the process of hosting a session as simple as possible, so that a user with no networking knowledge can accept incoming connections without having to configure their router or any other such thing. I was wondering how I could achieve this?

Comment: You are likely going to run into some serious firewall issues with this I would imagine...for good reason firewalls don't tend to like inbound connections without configuration.

Comment: Exactly, there are a lot of issues and I was wondering how most p2p systems handle them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to programatically update firewall rules, given the variation in network set ups, it's not possible to have a one size fits all approach. I think you have three choices, the last probably being the better:

1) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Gateway_Device_Protocol
2) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunneling_protocol
3) instructions for users to configure their routers (will be needed as a back-up for users who the first two fail for)